Exhibit all $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphisms in $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}\left ( \mathbb{Z}_{48}^{174}, \mathbb{Z}_{25}^{\mathbb{Q}} \right )$
My problem is:
Exhibit all $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphisms in $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}\left ( \mathbb{Z}_{48}^{174}, \mathbb{Z}_{25}^{\mathbb{Q}} \right )$, where $ \mathbb{Z}_{48}^{174}$ is the the direct sum of $174$
copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{48}$, and $\mathbb{Z}_{25}^{\mathbb{Q}}=\underset{i\in \mathbb{Q}}{\prod }A_{i}$ with $A_{i}=\mathbb{Z}_{25},\forall i \in \mathbb{Q}$.
My teacher suggests using this $Hom_{R}\left ( \underset{i\in I}{\bigoplus}A_{i},\underset{j\in J}{\prod}B_{j}  \right )\cong \underset{(i,j)\in I\times J}{\prod }Hom_{R}\left ( A_{i},B_{j} \right )$,
but I still don't understand the connection between the suggestion and my problem. I only find out that there is only one $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{48}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ which is a trivial  one.
It would be great if someone could give me some hints to solve this. Thanks for any help in advanced!

Your teacher's hint plus your observation that only a trivial homomorphism exists (can you prove this as a lemma?) should wrap up this question no? Maybe I am missing something.

@DerekAllums Yes, It's a lemma. My teacher introduced and proved it in class! He asked me to use it to solve the above problem! If we replace $\mathbb{Z}{25}$ by $\mathbb{Z}{15}$, then there are 3 homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}{48}$ to $\mathbb{Z}{15}$, what is the answer now? I really confused about this!

As suggested by my comment, you already have all the pieces:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}\left(\mathbb{Z}_{48}^{174}, \mathbb{Z}_{25}^{\mathbb{Q}} \right) & = \text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z} \left(\underset{i\in [1, \ldots,174]}{\bigoplus}\mathbb{Z}_{48},\underset{j\in \mathbb{Q}}{\prod}\mathbb{Z}_{25}  \right ) \\
& \simeq \prod_{i, j} \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left( \mathbb{Z}_{48}, \mathbb{Z}_{25} \right) \\
& \simeq \prod_{i, j} \lbrace 0 \rbrace \\
&\simeq \lbrace 0 \rbrace
\end{align}
$$
where $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ is the trivial morphism.
The first equality is just the definition, the second isomorphism is the lemma your professor cited, the second is your own observation, and the third is trivial.

Thanks!  But what if I replace from $\mathbb{Z}{48}, \mathbb{Z}{25}$ to $\mathbb{Z}{60}, \mathbb{Z}{15}$ respectively, then I find it difficult to describe the answer, since now I have $15$ homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}{60}$ to $\mathbb{Z}{15}$. Could you help?  Sorry for the inconvenience!

It's the exact same procedure. You get a direct product of a group you can describe very concretely, in fact, there is only one nontrivial group of order 15.

you mean this :
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Hom}\mathbb{Z}\left(\mathbb{Z}{60}^{174}, \mathbb{Z}{15}^{\mathbb{Q}} \right) & = \text{Hom}\mathbb{Z} \left(\underset{i\in [1, \ldots,174]}{\bigoplus}\mathbb{Z}{60},\underset{j\in \mathbb{Q}}{\prod}\mathbb{Z}{15}  \right ) \
& \simeq \prod_{i, j} \text{Hom}{\mathbb{Z}}\left( \mathbb{Z}{60}, \mathbb{Z}{15} \right) \
& \simeq \prod{i, j} \mathbb{Z}{gcd(60,15)} \
& \simeq \prod{i, j} \mathbb{Z}_{15}
\end{align}
$$

@NguyễnHữuNam Yes exactly. Are you concerned with any of the steps?
